# Best solution for storing blobs and tables with Azure for cross-platform mobile app

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-mobile-services

We are developing a vector drawing app for WP8/iOS/Android. We would like to use the following cloud features:

- Users should be able to upload their creations (binary data) to the cloud
- Users should be able to browse through others' creations and download, upvote/downvote those
- Users should be able to authenticate through their Facebook and/or Twitter, Google accounts

Questions:

1. Will we be able to implement this functionality with Azure? The core of application is written in C++ with native bindings for respective platforms, hence we should be able to use Azure mobile SDKs on all platforms.
2. Should we write additionally some server logic?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Storage can help with your first two requirements. See http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/storage/ for an overview and getting started documentation. Also see the Azure Storage team blog and the MSDN technical documentation.

Currently, Azure Storage provides shared key authentication, with support for delegated access via shared access signatures. You can find additional details on authentication at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh225339.aspx.